# Last header tag overwrites any previous tag with same name - expected behaviour?

Tags: templating

I am trying to add several header tags with the same name but different values. The last one prevails where the other don't appear to be output (when examining the output header using a sniffer). eg.

```
{% header "Link: </css/master.css>; rel=preload; as=style" %}
{% header "Link: </js/plugins.js>; rel=preload; as=script" %}
{% header "Link: </js/main.js>; rel=preload; as=script" %}
```

I'm trying to implement HTTP/2 server push for these files. Is this expected behaviour? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks like if you want to specify multiple values for a link header, you need to comma separate them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25416118/684

Comment: Ah ok, thanks Brad. Hopefully that will do the trick.